# I don't have LibraryPaths on my computer too?

Tags: revit-api, autodesk

```
RegistryKey hklm = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey libraryPath =hklm.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Autodesk\\ADSKTextureLibrary\\1\\2022");
_textureFolder = libraryPath.GetValue("LibraryPaths").ToString();
hklm.Close();
```

I want to reach "LibraryPaths" with this code, but I get a "null" error. Is there a link to the file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you raised the same question in the Revit API discussion forum as well: [I don't have LibraryPaths on my computer too?](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/i-don-t-have-librarypaths-on-my-computer-too/td-p/11341929)
So, here is the same suggestion I made there:

Does the [`GetLibraryPaths` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/4782f03c-9661-3bb5-0156-03ef96a2c69b.htm) provide the information you require?